# get specific value from simpleXMLElement array

Tags: php, arrays, simplexml

I have seen similar questions like this but none answered successfully. I have this simpleXMLElement turned array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [uri] => https://66.90.34.19:9630/api/users/2/
                    [id] => 2
                    [full_render] => true
                )

            [username] => Admin
            [password] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                )

            [name] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [first] => LightSpeed
                    [last] => Administrator
                )

            [email] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                )

            [account_locked] => false
            [privilege_group] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [uri] => https://66.90.34.19:9630/api/privilege_groups/0/
                            [id] => 0
                            [full_render] => false
                        )

                    [name] => Administrator
                    [type] => administrator
                )

            [read_eula] => true
            [hidden] => false
            [enabled] => true
            [phone] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                 (
                 )

            [product] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                )

            [product_code] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                )

            [open_to_pos] => false
            [gsx_tech_id] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                 (
                )

            [can_open_from_otr] => true
            [can_discount] => true
            [internal_user] => false
            [active] => true
            [expired] => false
        )

    [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [uri] => https://66.90.34.19:9630/api/users/2/
                    [id] => 2
                    [full_render] => true
                )

            [username] => Admin
            [password] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                )

             [name] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [first] => LightSpeed
                    [last] => Administrator
                )

            [email] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                )

            [account_locked] => false
            [privilege_group] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [uri] => https://66.90.34.19:9630/api/privilege_groups/0/
                            [id] => 0
                            [full_render] => false
                        )

                    [name] => Administrator
                    [type] => administrator
                )

            [read_eula] => true
            [hidden] => false
            [enabled] => true
            [phone] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                )

            [product] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                )

            [product_code] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                )

            [open_to_pos] => false
            [gsx_tech_id] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                 (
                 )

            [can_open_from_otr] => true
            [can_discount] => true
            [internal_user] => false
            [active] => true
            [expired] => false
        )
```

I want the echo the [name]->[first] and [name]->[last].

I have tried many versions of loops to get them by key name. I just can't figured it out. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SimpleXML objects can be treated like arrays.  Just loop through and get the data you need.

You access their data using `->` instead of `[]`.

```
foreach($array as $x){
    $name = $x->name;
    echo $name->first . ' ' . $name->last;
}
```

DEMO: http://codepad.viper-7.com/Ncn3C1

Comment: I tried that. It does not return anything. This is a simpleXMLElement inside an array. I had to do this in order to get the response from a previous loop. Even when I just try to echo $x is returns empty.

Comment: How are you getting this array?  What does `var_dump($x)` return?

Comment: foreach ($sest as $what=>$ok){
checksession();
$restNew2 = new RESTConnector();


$urlNew2 = "https://localhost:9630/api/users/".$ok."/";
$restNew2->createRequest($urlNew2,"GET", null, $_SESSION['cookies'][0]);
$restNew2->sendRequest();


$responseNew2 = $restNew2->getResponse();
 


$xmlNew2[] = new SimpleXMLElement($responseNew2);

}

foreach($xmlNew2 as $x){
    $name = $x['name'];
    echo (string)$name['first'];
 echo $x;
}
print_r($xmlNew2);

Comment: `$name = $x['name']` should be `$name = $x->name`, I've updated that in my answer.

Comment: sorry I don't know how to post code in comments. But as you can see because the response is from a previous loop I have to store the response in the array so I do not double up my other responses.

Comment: Is the code in the question the result of `print_r($xmlNew2);`?

Comment: So, does the code in my answer not work?  Note that it's using `->` instead of `[]`.

Comment: Got it! I changed the $name = $x->name but not the echo line. Thanks for your patience and help @Rocket!